# Reading from topic once using rospy.wait_for_message()

Tags: ros, rospy, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I want to read a message from a topic once, thus I tried to use `wait_for_message()` like this:

```
topic_name = "/yumi/rws/system_states"
system_info = rospy.wait_for_message(topic_name, SystemState, timeout=5)
```

but the timeout was reached, and I couldn't read a message from the topic!

The topic is publishing messages, and I was able to check them from the terminal using:

`rostopic echo "/yumi/rws/system_states"`, how can I read a message from the topic once? thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/392152/reading-from-topic-once-using-rospy.wait_for_message()/) by [bhomaidan](https://answers.ros.org/users/71460/bhomaidan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 114 on 2021-12-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-12-03**:\

> but the timeout was reached, and I couldn't read a message from the topic!

Can you tell me what error you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe you can unsubscribe from the topic after a 1-time call.

You can do so, by calling `subscriber.unregister()` this function.

```
def cb_once(msg, subscriber):
    #do processing here
    subscriber.unregister()

sub_once = None
sub_once = rospy.Subscriber('my_topic,', MyType, cb_once, sub_once)
```

Or

--
Solution

> not a ros node, can that be possibly the problem for endless waiting??

have you created rospy.init_node? If not, I think you cannot execute this line without initializing the node.

> system_info = rospy.wait_for_message(topic_name, SystemState, timeout=5)

This syntax it looks correct.

---

Originally posted by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) with karma: 1622 on 2021-12-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bhomaidan](https://answers.ros.org/users/71460/bhomaidan/) on 2021-12-03**:
@RanjitKathiriya There is no `spinOnce` in `rsopy`, and I have [read](https://answers.ros.org/question/110336/python-spin-once-equivalent/) that some users were able to use `wait_for_message` instead, that's why I do like to use it if possible, but I'm not sure if I'm using it correctly.

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-12-03**:\

> I have read that some users were able to use wait_for_message instead, that's why I do like to use it if possible

I have checked your syntax it looks correct. If possible can you re-edit your question and share the full code file. That's why I was asking for a detailed error in your question comment.

Moreover, you also can use `unregister()` this is also a good option to consider.

**Comment by [bhomaidan](https://answers.ros.org/users/71460/bhomaidan/) on 2021-12-03**:
@RanjitKathiriya  I'm using this line `system_info = rospy.wait_for_message(topic_name, SystemState, timeout=5)` inside a normal function, and **not a ros node**, can that be possibly the problem for endless waiting??

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-12-03**:\

> not a ros node, can that be possibly the problem for endless waiting??

have you created `rospy.init_node`? If not, I think you cannot execute this line without initializing the node.

> system_info = rospy.wait_for_message(topic_name, SystemState, timeout=5)

This syntax it looks correct.

**Comment by [bhomaidan](https://answers.ros.org/users/71460/bhomaidan/) on 2021-12-03**:
@RanjitKathiriya thanks, that solved my problem.

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-12-03**:
Tick the answer, if you got your answer. That can help others.